# Most efficient way to build list combining related fields

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have two models: `Vendor`, `Product`. The `Vendor` model has a `state` field. I'd like to create a page that lists the vendors in a certain state, grouped by product. Example output is:

> Vendors in Maryland
>
> - Product A
>
>   - Vendor 1
> - Product B
>
>   - Vendor 2
>   - Vendor 3
> - Product C
>
>   - Vendor 4
>   - Vendor 5

`Vendors` have `Product` as a `ForeignKey`. I can search the vendors by state name.

```
def vendor_by_state_page(request, state_name):
    vendors = Vendor.objects.filter(state=state_name)
    products = Products.objects.all()
```

I could do nested loops in the templates, but it seems inefficient:

```
{% for product in products %}
  <h2>{{product.name}}</h2>
  {% for vendor in vendors %}
    {% if vendor.product == product %}
       - {{vendor.display_name}}
    {% endif %}
  {% empty %}
    No {{product.name}} vendors in {{state.name}}.
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Plus, the empty doesn't actually work here because there are results, they just dont match the if. Ideally, I'd just not have the product show up on the list at all.

So, hopefully that's enough context. I'm sure I'm missing something. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Prefetch to filter the related set.

```
    from django.db.models import Prefetch
    products = Products.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
        'vendor_set',
        queryset=Vendor.objects.filter(
            state=state_name
        )
    ))
```

In the template just iterate:

```
{% for product in products %}
  <h2>{{product.name}}</h2>
  {% for vendor in product.vendor_set.all %}
   - {{vendor.display_name}}
  {% empty %}
   No {{product.name}} vendors in {{state.name}}.
  {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: tomas-walch - thank you! This worked, but `prefetch(state=state_name)` was giving me an error: `'Manager' object has no attribute 'prefetch'` .. so I removed it and all worked great. Is there an additional i can filter where the product isn't in the list if the vendor list is empty?

Comment: thanks. helpful! any thoughts on completely hiding products that have no vendors from the result / template?

Comment: Yes, that's easy. Filter the Product queryset on `vendor__state=state_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `related_name` :

If `Vendor` has `Product` as a `ForeignKey` you should have something like this in your `Model` :

```
class Vendor(models.Model):

    product      = models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name="vendors")
```

And now you will access to the vendors of a product like this :

```
{% for product in products %}
  <h2>{{product.name}}</h2>
  {% for vendor in product.vendors.all %}
       - {{vendor.display_name}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```